# Ip range vs subnet, docket bridge network

Tags: docker, networking, subnet

I want to [assign an IP range for a docker network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#specify-advanced-options) like so:

```
$ docker network create \
  --driver=bridge \
  --subnet=192.168.0.0/24 \ <=== I'm guessing here. Don't know what needs to go here.
  --ip-range=192.168.0.0/26 \
  --gateway=192.168.0.62 \ <===== Don't know what need to be here either
  br0
```

But I don't understand the reason for the subnet option.

What would the subnet be if I need to assign the bridge network the following IP range:

```
192.168.0.1 - 192.168.0.62
```

Also, what should the gateway be? I'm confused on how to create this network bridge correctly.

The reason why I need to specify a ip-range, is that I created a Docker bridge network and Docker assigned it a subnet that clashed with the IP of one sites I need to use and I couldn't reach my site anymore.

Comment: "_what should the gateway be?_" The gateway (router) is the address of the device on the network that knows how to route packets to other networks.

Comment: @RonMaupin Sure. Docker daemon will create the gateway right? I just need to pick its IP?

Comment: Some people always use the first network address, some always use the last network address, and it can be any address in the network, but you should try to be consistent.

Comment: Sure. That's how I thought it'll be. Okay. Now the main question. How do I pick the subnet given the ip range above?

Comment: @RonMaupin Forgot to say, thank you!!

Comment: Sorry, I just do not know enough about configuring that. Is the range the host address range, the DHCP range, or what is it? From the network perspective, the valid host address range starts at the subnet (archaic wording for network, as all networks are subnets of `0.0.0.0/0`) address plus one, and goes to the broadcast address minus one. [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) explains IPv4 addressing and subnetting, and there is even a section in there about choosing a gateway address, among many other things.

Comment: It's the range of addresses for the network bridge. So, I wonder why would you have more addresses in that subnet than the range of network bridge?

Comment: How many host should be in subnet? Most common case 192.168.1.0/24 (so range from 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255) .255 - is broadcast address for that subnet, .1 is gateway, 253 ip addresses for hosts. Similar to our case 192.168.0.0/26: Broadcast - 192.168.0.63, Gateway - Broadcast: 192.168.0.1, 61 ip address for hosts.

Comment: `--subnet` bascially delivers the subnet/prefix size to configure the veth network interfaces with, while the concrete IP addresses for the veth come from the `--ip-range`, not from `--subnet`.